# How can I check if a string is convertable to integer without isdigit or similar?

Tags: python, string, integer

I'm working on a project for university, and I need to use an integer from a user input. However I'm trying to make sure my code doesn't break as soon as someone types something the code wasn't expecting, a letter or word instead of a number for example.

After asking, I was told I'm not to use `isdigit()` or similar functions. Is there a way out of this or should I ignore this weak point in my code?

Comment: use a while loop with try except block. get input inside while loop. try to type cast the input to integer. if error print something like that is not an integer and continue the loop. if no error just break out of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

**Technically** this doesn't use any functions like `isdigit()`...

```
all(c in "0123456789" for c in string)
```

Examples:

```
>>> string = "239a0932"
>>> all(c in "0123456789" for c in string)
False
>>> string = "9390239"
>>> all(c in "0123456789" for c in string)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either just try to convert the input to an int, and if it fails with an exception, it wasn't a number. Or you use a regular expression.

```
import re

entered = input("Enter a text: ")

# Check as regular expression
pattern = re.compile(r"^\d+$")
if pattern.match(entered):
    print("re says it's a number")
else:
    print("re says it's not a number")

# Try to convert
try:
    asNum = int(entered)
    print("can be converted to a number")
except ValueError:
    print("cannot be converted to a number")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `try`/`except`:

```
try:
    num = int(input("Enter a number"))
except ValueError:
    # do whatever you want to do if it wasn't a valid number
```

If you want to re-prompt the user until they enter a number, and then go ahead with whatever you needed `num` for, that looks like:

```
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("Enter a number"))
        break  # end the loop!
    except ValueError:
        print("nope, try again!")
        # loop continues because we didn't break it

print(f"{num} + {num} = {num * 2}!")
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
if len(my_probably_digits_str) == len("".join([x for x in my_probably_digits_str if x in "0123456789"])):
    print("It's convertable!")
```